# Finding duplicate records in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to find duplicate records in Power Query. I do not need to remove them, I would just need to identify them. I am putting up a sample here.

[image]

As you can see in the image below, the first record is actually not a duplicate unlike the row below. 
I am pretty new to using power query and all I did here was what I would generally do in EXCEL: 
[image]

I was wondering if somebody could tell me what could I be doing wrong here. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is 
Right-click the ID column, Group By...

Click [Advanced]

It should default to Count Rows in the first row at bottom

[Add Aggregation] with New Column Name 'All" and operation 'All Rows'

[image]

Hit [OK]

Click on arrows at top of All column and [x] the ID column and any other columns that may have been there, here assumed to be called Other

[image]
[image]

The count column will be >1 for dupe rows.

Then you can remove extra columns and filter if wanted

Or add a custom column with formula

```
=if [Count]>1 then "Dupe" else "Single"
```

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}, {"All", each _, type table}}),
#"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"ID", "Other"}, {"ID.1", "Other"})
in #"Expanded All"
```